# How to refer to a child class from a parent method?

Tags: python

In the following sample, is there a magic word I can put in place of `<ChildClass>` that works like the opposite of super?

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print <ChildClass>.x

class someChild(Parent):
    x = 10
```

It is a stupid example, but it shows my intention. By the way, using `someChild` will not work, because there are many child classes.

The only solution I can think of is to have a constructor in every child class that calls the constructor of Parent with a reference to itself (or even to pass x), but I would like to avoid having a constructor at all in each child.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this shouldn't be possible because a parent can have many chidren.

Comment: @xbonez: I think he means when a single child class calls `Parent.__init__`, as in my example below.

Comment: @xbonez: Sorry I should have mentioned that the Parent class is never used by itself, it is only for subclassing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is wrong with just using `self.x`?

```
class Parent(object):
    x = None  # default value
    def __init__(self):
        print self.x

class someChild(Parent):
    x = 10
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

class otherChild(Parent):
    x = 20
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

a = someChild()
# output: 10
b = otherChild()
# output: 20
```

Note how this works even if `Parent` has a class attribute `x` as well (`None` in the above example)- the child's takes precedence.

Comment: Sometimes life can be simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`self.x` will work if the instance doesn't have an `x` attribute.

`type(self).x` if the instance has an `x` attribute and you want the class's value, essentially skipping over the instance.